# VB DLL Help - How to detect Sender

Tags: windows, vb.net, dll

I created a VB.NET and there are two projects in it. One is a class library with one class file (lets say Clas1.vb) and the other is just of a form.  I referenced the Class library into the other form so I could use its methods in it. However, the Class1.vb cannot pickup what project is using it. So how would I go about where a button on Form1 is clicked, and the code behind it is say, ClasslibraryInProject.Class1.MaximizeForm() the Class1.vb knows which project/form passed that command to it, and it then performs the Windowstate = FormWindowState.Maximized command on Form1. Any ideas?

Comment: try to revise your question :)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make your constructor require that the parent be associated with it:

```
Public Class Class1
    Private _parent as Form
    Public Sub New (form as Form)
        _parent = form
    End Sub
    '...
End Class
```

In your form, when you create it, you set that property in the constructor:

```
'...
Dim myClass1 as New Class1 (Me) ' The parent form
'...
```

Then, inside your Class1, you can test that property:

```
Public Class Class1
    Private _parent as Form
    Public Sub New (form as Form)
        _parent = form
    End Sub
    Public Sub DoStuff
        If _parent.Name = "whatever" Then
        '...
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

This is pretty standard, you'll see a similar behaviour from dialog boxes and message boxes within the .Net framework.

It's mildly disgusting to do this based on the name of the parent form. But that's a discussion for another day ;)

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler way to do this would be just to pass the form into your MaximizeForm function:

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Sub MaximizeForm(sender as Object)
        Select Case sender.Name
        Case "Form1"
            ' cast the sender as a form and maximize it
            Directcast(sender,Form).WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        Case Else
            ' ...
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Now how would I go about affecting the sender? Say maximizing it?

Comment: I've changed the code above to cast the sender as a form and maximize it.

Comment: Thanks, but how would I go about running this if the Class file is in a separate project but in the same solution as the form which has its own project?